# Angularjs : $locationChangeStart checking token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token

i'm try to check `next` if hasToken or not but not working i get error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
```

any idea ?

**app.js**

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location,$log,User) {

         $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event,next, current,jwtHelper) {

              if(!localStorage.token.next){

                location.path("/signin");
              }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

token is undefind

u can check like this

```
if(!localStorage.token || !localStorage.token.next){
            location.path("/signin");
          }
```

Comment: wrong because when i try to redict to home it's redict to /signin